# Wrong redirect after login to confluence homepage in stead of my app (using crowd)

Tags: single-sign-on, confluence, atlassian-crowd

I have confluence, jira and my own developed jsf application connected to crowd. This enabled SSO over the three applications.

When not logged in and requesting a url deep inside confluence, I get redirected to the confluence login page. I do the login and I get redirected to the previously demanded page. This is good.

But when I call a url from my own developed application (and I'm not logged in) I get redirected to the confluence login page (thsi is correct) but afterwards I get redirected to the confluence home page in stead of the page (my app) I initially requested.

How can I get the same behaviour in my own app?

Added some explanation about the integration:

code to see if a valid crowd token exists

```
authenticated = HttpAuthenticatorFactory.getHttpAuthenticator().isAuthenticated(
                (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest(),
                (HttpServletResponse)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse());
```

Comment: How are you integrating your custom app with Crowd? Can you give us some more details (maybe some code snippets)?

Comment: I added crowd jars (crowd-integration-client-2.2.7.jar) to my appliction. And when you access my application, the app checks if a valid crowd session is available. If it does not exist it redirects to the confluence login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. It was my app that redirecte to welcome page of confluence. So I added a os_destination= myself.